# Play framework zentasks tutorial groupBy

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm doing the zentasks tutorial.  I'm on this step located here

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaGuide3

I've covered up to the heading **Adding some style**.  Before that you are suppose to refresh the page and everything is suppose to be alright.

When I refresh I get the following error

[image]

I've been looking at this for a while now and cant figure out what I could be doing wrong.

Edit this is my code for this page

```
@(projects: List[Project])(body: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zentasks</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="@routes.Application.index" id="logo"><span>Zen</span>tasks</a>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <h4 class="dashboard"><a href="#/">Dashboard</a></h4>
            <ul id="projects">
                @projects.groupBy(_.folder).map{
                    case(group, projects) => {
                        @views.html.projects.group(group,projects)
                    }
                } 
                @projects(0).folder </br>
                @projects(1).folder </br>
                @projects(2).folder </br>
                @projects(3).folder </br>
                @projects(4).folder </br>
                @projects(5).folder </br>
                @projects(6).folder </br>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section id="main">
            @body
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it was really small.

the code

```
            @projects.groupBy(_.folder).map{
                case(group, projects) => {
                    @views.html.projects.group(group,projects)
                }
            }
```

Should be

```
            @projects.groupBy(_.folder).map{
                case (group, projects) => {
                    @views.html.projects.group(group,projects)
                }
            }
```

In case you don't see the difference (It took me 3 hours to find it!), there is a space after "case".  That's it.  My project compiles now.

Comment: Stack Overflow makes you wait 2 days to accept your own answer.